# How can I interact with print modal on Chrome in Python Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to interac with print modal on Chrome in Python Selenium to save capture as a PDF but I can't to use the same controls I use while interacting with the screen itself.
This  is the code I use to reach the the print modal view:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(join(abspath('.'), 'chromedriver.exe'), options=webdriver_options)
browser.get("[PAGE]")
browser.maximize_window()
search_field = browser.find_element_by_name("ELEMENT_NAME")  # find field to type the name
search_field.send_keys(name)
submit_field = browser.find_element_by_name("ELEMENT_NAME")  # find the submit button
submit_field.click()
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
browser.execute_script('return window.print()')
```

If I want iteract with modal, I can't to use `browser.find_element_by_name("ELEMENT_NAME")`, I used `browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[-1])` to switch to modal and it didn't work.

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

[image: Screen I want interact with]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve this problem using pdf, but using `browser.get_screenshot_as_file("[PATH]")` I get a screenshot and this work for me.